# Wrapping nnet::multinom() + ggeffects::ggemmeans() in a custom function fails though regular code works: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Tags: r, prediction, rlang, do.call, emmeans

I want to fit a multinomial model with `nnet::multinom()` and get predictions with `ggeffects::ggemmeans()`. Whereas such procedure works in regular code, I fail to wrap this in a function.

### Example

*Data*

```r
library(dplyr)

my_mtcars <- 
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(c(vs, carb), as.factor)) %>%
  as_tibble()
```

*Fitting and predicting works in the following way*

```r
library(nnet) # 7.3-15
library(emmeans) # 1.5.4
library(ggeffects) # 1.0.2

m <- multinom(carb ~ vs, data = my_mtcars)
ggemmeans(model = m, terms = "vs")

## # Predicted probabilities of carb
## # x = vs

## # Response Level = 1

## x | Predicted |       95% CI
## ----------------------------
## 0 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.00]
## 1 |      0.50 | [0.43, 0.57]

## # Response Level = 2

## x | Predicted |       95% CI
## ----------------------------
## 0 |      0.28 | [0.24, 0.32]
## 1 |      0.36 | [0.30, 0.42]

## # Response Level = 3

## x | Predicted |       95% CI
## ----------------------------
## 0 |      0.17 | [0.14, 0.19]
## 1 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.00]

## # Response Level = 4

## x | Predicted |       95% CI
## ----------------------------
## 0 |      0.44 | [0.39, 0.50]
## 1 |      0.14 | [0.12, 0.17]

## # Response Level = 6

## x | Predicted |       95% CI
## ----------------------------
## 0 |      0.06 | [0.05, 0.06]
## 1 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.00]

## # Response Level = 8

## x | Predicted |       95% CI
## ----------------------------
## 0 |      0.06 | [0.05, 0.06]
## 1 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.00]
```

**But when I try to wrap this procedure in a custom function it fails**

```r
my_multinom <- function(dat, dv, expl) {
  
  frmla <- as.formula(paste0(dv, "~", expl))
  
  model_fit <- nnet::multinom(frmla, data = dat)
  ggemmeans(model = model_fit, terms = expl)
}

my_multinom(dat = my_mtcars, dv = "carb", expl = "vs")
```

> Error in object$call$formula[[2]] :
> object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Notably, it seems that the problem lies in the interaction between `multinom()` and `ggemmeans()`. If we omit `ggemmeans()` from `my_multinom()` then it seems to work OK:

```r
my_multinom_no_ggemmeans <- function(dat, dv, expl) {
  
  frmla <- as.formula(paste0(dv, "~", expl))
  model_fit <- nnet::multinom(frmla, data = dat)
  model_fit
}

my_multinom_no_ggemmeans(dat = my_mtcars, dv = "carb", expl = "vs")

## # weights:  18 (10 variable)
## initial  value 57.336303 
## iter  10 value 38.192450
## iter  20 value 37.940409
## final  value 37.940164 
## converged
## Call:
## nnet::multinom(formula = frmla, data = dat)

## Coefficients:
##   (Intercept)       vs1
## 2    13.44961 -13.78607
## 3    12.93879 -33.99280
## 4    13.91961 -15.17237
## 6    11.84015 -23.96194
## 8    11.84015 -23.96194

## Residual Deviance: 75.88033 
## AIC: 95.88033
```

Any idea why `my_multinom()` wrapper fails?

---

UPDATE

---

I may have found a solution but I don't understand *why* it works. Based on [this github issue](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/252#issuecomment-334361907) (a different package), I've adapted the following solution:

```r
my_multinom_with_do.call <- function(dat, dv, expl) {

  frmla <- as.formula(paste0(dv, "~", expl))

  model_fit <- do.call(multinom, args = list(formula = frmla, data = dat))
  ggemmeans(model = model_fit, terms = expl)
}
```

And it works:

```r
my_multinom_with_do.call(dat = my_mtcars, dv = "carb", expl = "vs")
```

But why this works whereas my original `my_multinom()` didn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of lazy evaluation. The `call` member of `model_fit` has `formula = frmla`, unevaluated. The `emmeans` support for that model is expecting a formula there. It will work if you add a line to the original function:

```
my_multinom <- function(dat, dv, expl) {
    
    frmla <- as.formula(paste0(dv, "~", expl))
    
    model_fit <- nnet::multinom(frmla, data = dat)
    model_fit$call$formula <- frmla
    ggemmeans(model = model_fit, terms = expl)
}
```

The reason the `do.call` method does work is that `frmla` is evaluated when you create the list that is passed to `do.call`.

Comment: I added a step to evaluate the formula (in the environment for the model's terms) before extracting the 2nd element (lhs of the formula, needed to get the levels of the multinomial response). So, after the next **emmeans** update to CRAN (soon), the extra line will not needed.